Optional groups not matching when it should
I'm trying to create a regex to replace the parameters |arquivourl= and |arquivodata= to use only |wayb=, so I created the following:
Find: (\{\{(?:cite|citar?).*?)(?:\| ?(?:arquivodata|dataarquivo|archive-?date) ?=.*?(?=\|))?(.*?)\| ?(?:arquivourl|urlarquivo|archive-?url) ?= ?https?://web\.archive\.org/web/(\d+)/.*?(?=\||\})(.*?)(?:\| ?(?:arquivodata|dataarquivo|archive-?date) ?=.*?(?=\||\}))?(.*?)\}\}

Replace: $1$2|wayb=$3$4$5}}

It worked perfectly fine with templates written in the usual, like
<ref name="Story">{{citar web |url=<!--Removed link--> |script-title=ja:ストーリー｜テレビアニメ『先輩はおとこのこ』公式サイト |títulotrad=História {{!}} Site oficial da série de televisão de anime "Senpai Is an Otokonoko" |acessodata=2024-07-05 |website=senpaiha-otokonoko.com |arquivourl=http://web.archive.org/web/20240704160235/https://senpaiha-otokonoko.com/story/ |arquivodata=2024-07-04 |urlmorta=não}}</ref>

was replaced with
<ref name="Story">{{citar web |url=<!--Removed link--> |script-title=ja:ストーリー｜テレビアニメ『先輩はおとこのこ』公式サイト |títulotrad=História {{!}} Site oficial da série de televisão de anime "Senpai Is an Otokonoko" |acessodata=2024-07-05 |website=senpaiha-otokonoko.com |wayb=20240704160235|urlmorta=não}}</ref>

However, it's not always that |arquivodata= is after |arquivourl=. In these other cases, it's not working as intended. For example,
<ref name="Devlin">{{citar jornal|último1=Devlin |primeiro1=Hannah |título=Ring discovered around dwarf planet Quaoar confounds theories |url=<!--Removed link--> |acessodata=8 de fevereiro de 2023 |obra=[[The Guardian]] |data=8 de fevereiro de 2023 |arquivodata=8 de fevereiro de 2023 |arquivourl=https://web.archive.org/web/20230208163722/https://www.theguardian.com/science/2023/feb/08/ring-discovered-around-dwarf-planet-quaoar-confounds-theories |urlmorta=não}}</ref>

was replaced with
<ref name="Devlin">{{citar jornal|último1=Devlin |primeiro1=Hannah |título=Ring discovered around dwarf planet Quaoar confounds theories |url=<!--Removed link--> |acessodata=8 de fevereiro de 2023 |obra=[[The Guardian]] |data=8 de fevereiro de 2023 |arquivodata=8 de fevereiro de 2023 |wayb=20230208163722|urlmorta=não}}</ref>

|wayb= shouldn't be used with |arquivourl= or |arquivodata=, that's why it needs to be removed. If I remove the question mark of one of the (?:\| ?(?:arquivodata|dataarquivo|archive-?date) ?=.*?(?=\||\})) group, it works correctly. However, I'd need to use two regexes this way, one when |arquivourl= is before |arquivodata=, and the other when it is after.
Is it possible to create a single regex to do this?

The regexp is matched in order. If there can be multiple orders, you need multiple regular expressions to handle the different cases.

Are you doing this in a programming language or an editor's find/replace? In a programming language, you can match the keywords in any order, and use a function as the replacement. It can use code to perform the replacements based on the keywords.

It's either Wikipedia built-in find/replace or VSCode one

After posting this an idea popped into my head, instead of using an optional group ?, I replaced with a group with a pipe indicating both cases. For example, if I wanted to match either lorem something ipsum or ipsum something lorem, it'd be (lorem.*?ipsum|ipsum.*?lorem) instead of (lorem)?.*?ipsum.*?(lorem)?. Now my regex became this:
Find: (\{\{(?:cite|citar?).*?)(?:(?:\| ?(?:arquivodata|dataarquivo|archive-?date) ?=.*?(?=\|))(.*?)\| ?(?:arquivourl|urlarquivo|archive-?url) ?= ?https?://web\.archive\.org/web/(\d+)(?:[a-z]{2}_)?/.*?(?=\||\})(.*?)\}\}|\| ?(?:arquivourl|urlarquivo|archive-?url) ?= ?https?://web\.archive\.org/web/(\d+)(?:[a-z]{2}_)?/.*?(?=\||\})(.*?)(?:\| ?(?:arquivodata|dataarquivo|archive-?date) ?=.*?(?=\||\}))(.*?)\}\})

Replace: $1|wayb=$2$5$3$4$6$7}}

Until now, it's working correctly, but I still need to test a little bit more.
